# How to generate unique string from users input?

Tags: algorithm, unique, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

For example, user can submit `$a`, `$b` and `$c`. and I need to create a unique string from these inputs.

If I use `$uniq = $a$b$c`, the input `$a=AB, $b=CD, $c=EF` and `$a=A, $b=BCD, $c=EF` both generate `$uniq=ABCDEF`.

If I use  `$uniq = $a|$b|$c`, then `$a=AB, $B=CD, $c=EF|` and `$a=AB|CD, $b=EF, $c=""` both generate `$uniq=AB|CD|EF|`

How can I do this?

Comment: Simple solution: use a separator character that the user is unable or not allowed to enter - a control character, perhaps.  More complex: prefix each input with its own length (as a single binary byte, or a decimal number followed by a colon, etc.).

Comment: As @jasonharper said, but you don't need to pick a single character separator. Any string that the user isn't allowed to enter will work.

Comment: This is a well-known problem. Consider C strings, where you have to "escape" the `'\'` character. So if you want to print the string `"\hello\"`, you write `puts("\\hello\\");` Similarly, you can separate the user's input with the `|` character, and if the user inputs a `|`, you convert it to `||`. Of course, you'll want to do the reverse conversion if you ever output the unique string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper and secure solution would be to generate separate hash values for `$a`, `$b` and `$c` and then combine those hashes together by concatenating or generating another hash.

Here is an algorithm:

```
$a_h = hash($a)
$b_h = hash($b)
$c_h = hash($c)
$uniq = hash($a_h$b_h$c_h)
```

Depending on your requirements, there is also might be a need to add a "salt" to make it even more secure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: A hash is not a unique value. Multiple strings can hash to the same value. Whereas it would be highly unlikely for a duplicate to appear, the possibility exists.

Comment: @JimMischel sure, that is why there are perfect hash functions ;) On the other hand, consider a unique value concatenated from a 3 times 100K of user input (as you suggested in the comment)... Anyway, using an appropriate hash function is more secure that any direct user input usage...